# add image at header & footer on every page of pdf using dompdf

Tags: php, html, css, pdf

I am trying to create pdf file using dompdf. 
I want to show header and footer images on every page of pdf, but my problem is in html I know that, but it's too large html code so I am googled some other solution like used here https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/807. 
This code is fine for textual header and footer but problem at adding image I tried my best for it but no use and getting the error like "Call to undefined method CPDF_Adapter::page_script() in filepathname.php".
Here is my code of generating pdf

```
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($message2);
$dompdf->set_paper('a4','portrait');
$dompdf->render();

$canvas = $dompdf->get_canvas();

//For Header
$header = $canvas->open_object();
$font = Font_Metrics::get_font("helvetica", "bold");
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$canvas->page_text(35, 25, "HiveDesk Screenshot Report", $font, 8, array(0, 0, 0));
$canvas->page_text(490, 25, "hivedesk.com", $font, 8, array(0, 0, 0));
$canvas->close_object();
$canvas->add_object($header, "all");

//For Footer
$footer = $canvas->open_object();
$font = Font_Metrics::get_font("helvetica", "bold");
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$canvas->page_text(250, 800, "Page: {PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}", $font, 8, array(0, 0, 0));

$canvas->page_script('$image = '.$header_image1.';
                      $pdf->image($image, 400, 25, 100, 25);
                    ');

$canvas->close_object();
$canvas->add_object($footer, "all");

$output = $dompdf->output();
$filename ="pdf/".time().".pdf";
file_put_contents("$filename",$output);
```

**Note:** $message2 contains all my html content. 
Can anyone please give me a solution? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've never used the library you are using. But Once I faced a similar problem and after trying different solutions I finally found an awesome pdf manipulation library but in java.... It's called iText. Here's my github experience if you find useful  https://github.com/web20opensource/stamper